# Sending a simple variable from AS3 to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, variables, actionscript

I have a flash-based tutorial screen that pops up as an overlay to HTML. The overlay is being implemented through standard javascript. My question is how can I simply pass a variable from As3 so that Javascript can use it.

I basically have 3 screens within the tutorial, and on the final screen I want to pass a variable to the javascript so it can activate an additional set of commands. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

D

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170504/actionscript-and-javascript-communication

Comment: @harsha why link a  question with no answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171571/actionscript-and-javascript-conversation

Comment: http://viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication

Answer (score 1):

Define a function in JS (say *myFunc*). Call it from AS3 & pass the variable (say *myVar*) like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("myFunc", myVar);
```

Comment: Thank you for the asssistance :)

Comment: please close question by checking the green tick, if this answer solved your probem.